# Dataformatstring property of a grid is not being set from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, grid

I am trying to set the Dataformatstring of a grids' boundfield column to some format. But it is not getting applied.

```
 GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
 BoundField a= (BoundField)grid.Columns[2];
 BoundField b= (BoundField)grid.Columns[3];
 BoundField c= (BoundField)grid.Columns[4];

 a.DataFormatString = "{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal + "}";
 b.DataFormatString = "{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal + "}";
 c.DataFormatString = "{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal + "}";
```

But there is no change in the values of the grids column. Here GridRoundOffDecimal is a value from database,which currently I have set to 2(indicating 2 decimal places after decimal point).

P.S. I know that this can be done in the aspx file itself by setting the `DataFormatString` property to `"{0:N2}"`, understand that the number of decimal places is dynamically set from database.

Your thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is on a `DataTable`, I think it is easier if you do it before your `DataBind()` function.  Like this:

```
// Change decimal places and pass the DataTable to the GridView
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    double newValue = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["ColumnNameToChange"]);
    dt.Rows[i]["ColumnNameToChange"] = String.Format("{0:N" + GridRoundoffDecimal.ToString() + "}", newValue);
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, i would have done that already  if it wasn't for a different requirement of the application, which is to calculate the sum of  each  column of the grid and display it in the footer. So I want the sum of the column to be calculated with the original values from the database(which include all the decimals), but i would only display may be up to 2 decimal places in the grid. So trying to modify the data-table wouldn't serve my purpose.

Comment: In that case, I will use [Crystal Reports](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) to display your data.  The code on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34434651/make-the-data-of-datagridview-as-source-for-crystal-report-vb2013/34439291#34439291) will help you.