# make the data of datagridview as source for crystal report vb2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i'm trying to print the data of a datagridview using crystal reports, i found an idea of filling a data table with the dgv then make it as a data source for the cr report
the problem is the report shows nothing ! 
and when i drag the database fields from the field explorer of crystal report, the report shows the whole data stored in the table .. not the dgv data !
any help ??
i tested the data table to check if it's filled with data by this

```
    Dim c As Integer
    For c = 0 To dg.RowCount - 2 Step 1
        dtd.Rows(c).Item(0) = dg.Rows(c).Cells(2).Value
        dtd.Rows(c).Item(1) = dg.Rows(c).Cells(3).Value
    Next
    TT.Text = dtd.Rows(3).Item(1)
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New dispexp
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dtd)

    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

the TT.text displays the data of dgv which i want, but the report shows blank :(

Answer (score 0):

I hope this C# example helps you:

```
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Load the report path
    string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt");
    rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc; 
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt");
        rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName1", typeof(String));      
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName2", typeof(String));
    dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName3", typeof(String));
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in yourDataGridView.Rows)      // <-- Here is where you transfer the data from your DataGridView into the DataTable
    {
      dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells["ColumnName1"].Value, dgr.Cells["ColumnName2"].Value, dgr.Cells["ColumnName3"].Value);
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt); 
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);


}

protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CrystalReportViewer1.Dispose();
    this.CrystalReportViewer1 = null;
    rptDoc.Close();
    rptDoc.Dispose();
    rptDoc = null;
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: C# is very similar to VB.  I think you can get the idea.

Comment: I tried but it displays some data not shown in the dgv !

Comment: The important part of this code is the `foreach` loop and the two lines after that `dsTables.Add(dt)` and `rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)`.  Make sure you are passing the `DataSet` that was loaded with the `GridView` data to the `prtDoc.SetDataSource()` function.  I know this code works.

Comment: For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In Me.dg.Rows
            dtcl.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("code").Value, dr.Cells("clientname").Value, dr.Cells("material").Value, dr.Cells("buyqty").Value, dr.Cells("saleprice").Value, dr.Cells("ddate").Value)
        Next
        ds.Tables.Add(dtcl)
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
i tried this but some data which is not in the dgv also apear on report

Comment: I noticed that if i removed the ds from report datasource the report still displays the same data !! Is it because iam draging the database fields from crystal report field explorer ?? ! , iam displaying data from 2 tables linked by one to many relationship

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are doing.  I thought you were working on a ASP.Net Web application.  The code I wrote as Answer is for a Web application.  I guess you are using a Windows Form.  Am I right?